# Need a modification in the regular expression

Tags: regex

I have regular expressions

```
'\d{2}[-/.]\d{2}[-/.]\d{4}' # For dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy.
```

But, it is also pulling out `dd-mm.yyyy` or `dd/mm-yyyy` from the string. I need a strict match for the dates i.e. `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Comment: I would just do all 3 formats separated with a `|`,  but I'm not too great with regex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
\d{2}([-/.])(\d{2}|[a-zA-Z]{3})\1\d{4}
```

`([-/.])` will match `-`, `/` or `.` as a group, and `\1` anywhere in this regex will refer to the same text matched by the group.

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/pM2jE7/2).

Comment: Using your suggestion I tried writing this regex - `\d{1,2}([-/.])\b\w{3}\b\1\d{2,4}` which should match for `dd-mon-yyyy` (example - 30-dec-2015). But it also matches for 30-333-2015. Is there any way to validate this ? or should it be done through programming ?